# Is it possible to insert null(" ") value to the datetime field in the database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sqldatetime

I have two fields DOB(date of birth) and (date of joining) If user enter the date then in the database
 insert->date else insert->null

I have define **properties** as

```
  public DateTime DOB
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public DateTime DOJ
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
```

Now in save_click event

```
        IFormatProvider provider = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-CA", true);
        String datetime = txtDOB.Text.Trim();
        DateTime date = DateTime.Parse(datetime, provider, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.NoCurrentDateDefault);
        objEmp.DOB = date;

        provider = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-CA", true);
        datetime = txtDOJ.Text.Trim();
        date = DateTime.Parse(datetime, provider, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.NoCurrentDateDefault);
        objEmp.DOJ = date;
```

**class.cs**

```
        param[7] = new Service.SqlParameter();
        param[7].ParameterName = "@DOB";
        param[7].Value = DOB;
        param[7].SqlDbType = Service.SqlDbType.DateTime;

        param[8] = new Service.SqlParameter();
        param[8].ParameterName = "@DOJ";
        param[8].Value = DOJ;
        param[8].SqlDbType = Service.SqlDbType.DateTime;
```

I want that when user did not insert any date then null should be inserted... But by this code i am getting an error
**Store procedure**

```
@FK_EmployeeTypeID Numeric(18,0),
    @EmployeeName NVARCHAR(50), 
    @CellNo  NVARCHAR(50),  
    @PhNo  NVARCHAR(50),    
    @Address  NVARCHAR(Max),    
    @Email  NVARCHAR(50),   
    @DOB DATETIME,
    @DOJ DATETIME,
    @DOR NVARCHAR(12),
    @Status NVARCHAR(50),
    @Remarks NVARCHAR(Max)

AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    BEGIN TRY
        BEGIN TRANSACTION Employee_Insert
    INSERT 
    INTO
    Employee
    (
        FK_EmployeeTypeID,
        EmployeeName,   
        CellNo, 
        PhNo,   
        Address,    
        Email,  
        DOB,
        DOJ,
        DOR,
        Status,
        Remarks

    )
    VALUES
    (

        @FK_EmployeeTypeID,
        @EmployeeName,  
        @CellNo,    
        @PhNo,  
        @Address,   
        @Email, 
        @DOB,
        @DOJ,
        @DOR,
        @Status,
        @Remarks
    )

        COMMIT TRANSACTION Employee_Insert
    SELECT '1'
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        SELECT 'Error : ' + ERROR_MESSAGE()
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION Employee_Insert
    END CATCH
```

**Webservice**

```
[WebMethod]
    public string InsUpdDel(string Conn, string ProcName, SqlParameter[] p)
    {
        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(Conn))
            {
                if (cn.State == ConnectionState.Open || cn.State == ConnectionState.Broken || cn.State == ConnectionState.Connecting || cn.State == ConnectionState.Executing || cn.State == ConnectionState.Fetching)
                    cn.Close();
                cn.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(ProcName, cn);

                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                foreach (SqlParameter param in p)
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
                }
                SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                dr.Read();
                if (dr[0].ToString() == "1")
                {
                    return "1";
                }
                else
                {
                    return dr[0].ToString();
                }
                dr.Close();
                cn.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return "Error : " + ex.Message.ToString();
        }
```

Comment: Is the column defined as nullable in the database table? Then yes. Also: don't just tease us *I am getting an error* - please **LET US KNOW** exactly what that error is! (we can't read your screen nor your mind, you know.....)

Comment: Also, `" "` is not null. It is a string literal. `NULL` is NULL.

Comment: Error:String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Comment: Learn about 1) `Nullable<DateTime>` (alias `DateTime?`) and 2) DateTime.TryParse. You are getting an error if the user doesn't enter a date because you are using a Parse method that throws exceptions. And if you want to insert nulls into the database, you need types that support that. Both in code, and in the database.

Comment: catch (Exception ex) { Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Error", string.Format("<script type='text/javascript'>alert('{0}')</script>", ex.Message.ToString())); } after calling insert() method the statement goes to catch

Comment: possible duplicate of [inserting null values in datetime column and integer column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2456755/inserting-null-values-in-datetime-column-and-integer-column)

Answer (score 1):

First you need to check you date column will accept null values or not.
If not then allow null there.

and then you can use

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param", DBNull.Value);
```

combining all will look like this

```
 param[8] = new Service.SqlParameter();
 param[8].ParameterName = "@DOJ";
 param[8].Value = DOJ==null?DBNull.Value:DOJ;
 param[8].SqlDbType = Service.SqlDbType.DateTime;
```

And your property should be like this

```
public DateTime? DOJ
{
    get;
    set;
}
```

Comment: @Yasser I was updating my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make 3 changes for your code to work,

**Change 1 :** First make your DateTime variable to [DateTime?](http://www.dotnetperls.com/nullable-datetime)

```
public DateTime? DOB { get; set; }
public DateTime? DOJ { get; set; }
```

**Change 2 :** Use DateTime.TryParse instead

```
DateTime DOB;
IFormatProvider provider = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-CA", true);
String datetime = txtDOB.Text.Trim();
DateTime.TryParse(datetime, provider, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.NoCurrentDateDefault, out DOB);
if (DOB != DateTime.MinValue)
{
    objEmp.DOB = null; 
}
else
{
    objEmp.DOB = date;
}
```

do same for DOJ.

**Change 3 :** Also when the value of datetime is null, make sure that when you are assiging the value of DOB to the sql parameter have a null check and if DOB is null then assign `DBNull.Value`

*For example :*

```
param[7].ParameterName = "@DOB";
if(DOB == null)
{
    param[7].Value = DBNull.Value;
}
else
{
    param[7].Value = DOB;   
}
param[7].SqlDbType = Service.SqlDbType.DateTime;
```

and yes welcome to Stackoverflow !

Comment: @ yasser  Still its not working... i m getting this error: "There was an error in generating XML document". I have add the SP in my question. I think the issue is now with SP

Comment: which line is giving the error ? please post the error, line number, stack trace etc

Comment: catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Error", string.Format("<script type='text/javascript'>alert('{0}')</script>", ex.Message.ToString()));
        } after calling insert() method the statement goes to catch

Comment: I have add the webservice method... any issue in that??

Comment: maybe... cant tell, your initial problem relating to this question is solved, so you can mark one of the answers and post a new question with full details of what is happening

Answer (score 1):

this code is worked for insert null vales in datetime field in sql

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@from_date", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DBNull.Value;
```

Comment: also use this                                  cmd.Parameters.Add("@from_date", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DBNull.Value;

Answer (score 0):

Make your properties nullable

```
public DateTime? DOB
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public DateTime? DOJ
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
```

and make your code like this

```
IFormatProvider provider = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-CA", true);
        String datetime = txtDOB.Text.Trim();

if(DateTime.TryParse(datetime, provider, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.NoCurrentDateDefault, out date))
{
  objEmp.DOB = date;
}
```

Comment: Still its not working... i m getting this error: "There was an error in generating XML document"

Comment: [Here is the answer][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15020551/webservice-method-returns-errorthere-is-an-error-in-generating-an-xml-document